# Trying to use serial devices with webIOPi

Tags: serial, webiopi

I was following this tutorial: http://webiopi.trouch.com/Tutorial_Serial.html
so I can make serial communication using the On-board serial UART

I couldn't find the file /etc/inittab, I skipped that step because I read that this file doesn't exist in Jessie.

Then I edited /boot/cmdline.txt and it says that I need to remove references to ttyAMA0.

This is what I find in that file:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p7 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

Should I erase the serial0? I got really confused by this and I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should NOT edit `/boot/cmdline.txt` but make changes in `raspi-config`.

If you don't want to use the serial console you can remove it by either means.

You don't say which model Pi you are using. The Pi3 uses `/dev/ttyAMA0` for Bluetooth and swaps the miniUART to the serial pins.

You can use `/dev/ttyAMA0` on an older Pi or `/dev/ttyS0` on Pi3. In the latest software there should be a `/dev/serial0` which selects the appropriate device.

There appears to be some problems on the Pi3 with varying baudrate.

I modified the `/boot/config.txt` by adding the following line at the end:-

```
core_freq=250
```

Comment: I am using the Pi 2 and the last version of Raspbian Jessie. If I am not supposed to change that file, why this tutorial tells me to do so? I should skip that step as well?

Comment: @LuzA I assume by "this tutorial" you mean that in your question. That refers to an older version of Raspbian using SysV and is obsolete. I have never used webIOP so can't comment on the other content. To disable console use `raspi-config` to make changes. If you want background see [How-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697)

Comment: To achieve the serial communication in this new version of Raspbian, I need to disable console and add `core_freq=250` to the config file, right? and leave alone the `cmdline.txt`

Comment: @LuzA Run `sudo raspi-config` select `Advanced Options` then `A8 Serial` That is ALL you need to do to disable console. The core_freq is for Pi3 (but wouldn't hurt).

Comment: This worked!! thank you, I just marked your answer as correct.